# Ionic on input focus keyboard is not showing

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Ionic input keyboard is not showing on click.

I have tried to fire function on click input but nothing happens.

I have attached gif image for the actual problem.

[image]

Need your help.

Thanks a lot

I have pasted `ionic` info below:

λ ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\ampkona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.9.4
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 7
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, but I think this happened due to some stylesheet conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with the same issue. I found a div with a class called input-cover. This class has a position absolute that overlaps the input. Hope it isn't too late for my answer.

Comment: And how should be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Press CMD + K while on the emulator and then click the input field.

also use  CMD + T to disable slow animations